# Show Multiple Users Location on Google/Apple Maps with Blue Marble Drop

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, ios5, mapkit

So What i need to do here is, I need to show Two users locations on the map with the Default Blue Marble Drop.

Task is, a user-A will keep uploading current location coordinates every 5-10 secs to web-server, from there the user-B will be pulling that location every 5-10 secs. So on the MKMapView, User-B will be shown his own current location with the default location annotation, but i also need to show User-A's location on the User-B's mapView with some annotation.

Now i can not use Pin Annotation as the location will be updating every 5-10 secs. The Default User Annotatio (Blue Marble Drop) has to be shown for second User's Pulled Location so that a user can get that the location of second User is not static, but on the move. Pin Annotation kind of suggest that the location is static.

How can i Achieve that?

Comment: why you can't use Pin Annotation?

Comment: When looking at a Pin, it conveys the message that the location is static, lets say a Bus Stop, or a Hotel, bu for a moving object, its not that appropriate.

Comment: i believe a custom pinView with Pin Annotation will work for you.

Comment: Yeah that would Do..! Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)updateLocation
{// this will update your location
    NSString *latitude = @"0.0";
    NSString *longitude=@"0.0";
    MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude Longitude:longitude];
    [self.theMapView removeAnnotations:[self.theMapView annotations]];
    [self.theMapView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addAnnotation:) withObject:ann waitUntilDone:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1f, 0.1f));
    [self.theMapView setRegion:region];

}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                  initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueMarbleDrop"];

    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    return pinView;
}
```

[image: Here is the BlueMarbleDrop.png]